# Create word pairs from list and assign value for each word pair

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list:

```
s = ['apple','orange','banana'.'strawberry','mango']
```

I would like to create pairs for  first word and other words:

```
s = [('apple','orange'),('apple','banana'),('apple','strawberry'),('apple','mango')]
```

And then, I would like  to assign values for each word pair:

```
 s = [('apple','orange',4),('apple','banana',3),('apple','strawberry',2),('apple','mango',1)]
```

Comment: What is the "value"? Is it always decreasing numbers ending in 1 as in your example?

Comment: Also, where's your code so far? What have you tried, and where did you run into trouble?

Comment: Try to add some code what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am new to python and I can't try this  code properly.I need this for my thesis purpose.I need to create graph edges with weight values to create graph with  networkx.Weight values assign with proportional weighting method,and so the nearest one to first token is the greatest number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may do what you want, though I'm not sure you've explained the problem thoroughly enough to know what the "value" (third element of each tuple) is supposed to be:

```
s = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'mango']

print [(s[0], s[i], len(s) - i) for i in range(1, len(s))]

# [('apple', 'orange', 4), ('apple', 'banana', 3), ('apple', 'strawberry', 2), ('apple', 'mango', 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer .